# Count total posts belonging to main category and subcategories in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to count total number of posts belonging to a main category and its subcategories in PHP/MySQL. I have three tables given by:

**tb_categories**

[image]

**tb_posts**

[image]

**tb_posts_to_categories**

[image]

Now to get total number of posts belonging to a category and all its subcategories, I am using the following code:

```
<?php
include("includes/db-config.php");

// Create connection
$connection = @mysqli_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME) 
or die(mysqli_connect_error());

    // Get total number of posts in a category
    function get_post_counts($category_id)
    {
        global $connection;
        $category_to_post = array();

        // Build database query
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(`post_id`) AS `post_count`, `category_id` FROM `tb_posts_to_categories`  GROUP BY `category_id`";

        // Execute database query
        $rs = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs))
        {
            $category_to_post[$row['category_id']] = $row['post_count']; 
        }

        // Build database query
        $sql2 = "SELECT `category_id`, `category_parent` FROM `tb_categories` WHERE `category_parent` <> 0";

        // Execute database query
        $rs2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql2);

        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs2))
        {
            $category_to_post[$row2['category_parent']] += $category_to_post[$row2['category_id']]; 
        }

        return $category_to_post[$category_id];
    }

$total_posts = get_post_counts(2);

echo $total_posts;

?>
```

**Output**

11

But this output is not correct. It should be equal to 8. But if you supply subcategory id then output is correct. It only mess up when parent category id is supplied to the function.

Since I have one-to-many relationship. A post can be assigned to several categories and even to its subcategories. The posts associated to more than two categories (One main category and its subcategories) are calculated again which yields me result 11 instead of 8.

However the code works fine when a post is associated to two different parent categories or their any subcategories. The issue is only when a post is associated to a main category and its multiple subcategories. How can we fix such wrong calculation? Please help me on this guys. Thanks!

Comment: Try with `SELECT COUNT(distinct post_id) AS post_count` in your main query

Comment: It didn't work. We must need `category_id` in our main query. Using \`COUNT(DISTINCT \`post_id\`)\` alone can not work. We get error then. And using it with `category_id` has no effect. Same result.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to count posts in category and it's direct subcategories.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT post_id)
FROM (
  (SELECT post_id
  FROM tb_posts_to_categories
  WHERE category_id = 2)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT pc.post_id
  FROM tb_posts_to_categories pc
    JOIN tb_categories c ON pc.category_id = c.category_id
  WHERE c.category_parent = 2)
) AS t
```

This is another, smaller variant :-)
But MySQL sometimes gets stucked with indexes usage if `WHERE` contains `OR` condition.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pc.post_id)
FROM tb_posts_to_categories pc
  JOIN tb_categories c ON pc.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE c.category_parent = 2 OR c.category_id = 2
```

Comment: Ok though it worked but seems to be a bit more complex and lengthy. Do we not have some other simpler solution?

Comment: OK, I have added smaller example.

Comment: Wow! That worked like a charm. You saved my day. Hats off to you @Andrew. Thanks.

Comment: Remember this example only works on **direct** subcategories. 2nd level subcategories are not counted.

Comment: Oh yes, the post count is not correct for post belonging to main category indirectly. How to overcome this?

Comment: Your question does not contain info about count all subcategories recursively. Your example is limited by one level, and answer contains note: "category and it's direct subcategories". I think, this is correct answer for such case. If you want to get recursively all possible subcategories, you will need dynamic sql. For example, inside stored procedure.